# Show blog posts in sidebar (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want create a blog posts list in the sidebar.
My BlogsController

```
def bloglist
  @blog = Blog.all
  render 'bloglist'
end
```

And I call bloglist.html.erb in layout/application.html.erb:

```
<%= render "blogs/bloglist" %>
```

After, I got missing template error:

> Missing partial blogs/bloglist with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths...

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an error on your file naming.

A **partial view** must always begin with an underscore. In this case, your partial view must be `app/views/blogs/_bloglist.html.erb`.

When you call render on a view and pass 'blogs/bloglist', that's the file it's going to look for.

You should also be aware that by calling that partial it will **not** call the controller action by default. If you want to get the blog list on every action rendering, you should use a before_filter on your ApplicationController.

Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :get_blog_list

  protected
  def get_blog_list
    @blog = Blog.all
  end
end
```